# VSCode cannot locate path in Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, filereference

I am using VSCode to learn about the library ngx-bootstrap.

The problem I am having however is that VSCode cannot recognize some of the paths used in the project (and I can't either!)

For example, in one file, some code is imported from `'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader'` yet there is no directory by that name anywhere, let alone relative to the file in question. ([GitHub link here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/typeahead/typeahead.directive.ts#L19))

My question is, how does this code work when the file references do not?

Comment: it's on node_modules/ folder, those paths are (should) created when you run `npm install`, the corresponding packages should be listed in package.json file at the root of the project beforehand

Comment: maybe it was *implied* that some packages are installed globally in a tutorial you found.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `npm install` did not run correctly.

Once I got it running properly, the problem disappeared